# Sorting with limited memory and read-only disk

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

Imagine the following scenario: I have a 10 Mb array of integers stored on a read-only storage medium. I wish to print out the numbers in ascending order. However, I only have 2 Mb of main memory (and no hard disk).

A very simple O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution (which doesn't make use of the available main memory) would be to repeatedly scan the entire input array and incrementally output the next smallest integer. I've tried googling for better sorting algorithms, but the answers keep leading me to in-place or external sorting algorithms, which would not work because of the read-only storage constraint. Is there a better solution?

Comment: no other constraints like no duplicate integers in the array or limited range ?

Comment: They are 32-bit integers and duplicates are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the main memory to reduce the number of scans, with the relation o sizes you gave, quite dramatically.

First scan: Keep an in-memory store of nearly the main memory size with the smallest numbers found so far. While the store is not yet full, add the next number read from the array. When the store is full, compare to the largest number in the store, if the new one is smaller, remove the largest number and add the new one. When the complete array has been scanned, output the found numbers in order, remember the largest number stored and how often that occurred in this chunk.

Subsequent scans: If the number scanned equals the largest number from the previous chunk and its occurrence count is smaller than its count from the previous scan, increment its occurrence count, but don't add it to the store, if its occurrence count is larger than or equal to the remembered count add the number to the store (removing the largest number from the store if necessary). If the scanned number is larger than the largest number of the previous scan, but smaller than the largest number in the store (or the store is not yet full), add it to the store (remove largest number if necessary). When the scan is complete, output the stored numbers in order, and remember the largest number output so far, and the number it has been output in total (the largest number might be the same as the one from the previous scan, so you need to know how often it was output in all chunks treated so far).

I'm not sure what the best data structure for the store would be, but I think a heap would be a good choice (comparison with largest: O(1), replacing: O(log size), final sorting for output: O(size*log size), practically no memory overhead as you would have with a binary search tree).